# Updating Embedded List in Mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

Does anyone know the mongodb syntax to update one item in a list of the document. Here is a sample of document. For example I want to update the StartTime for id 524725e61788d8078c900afb

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "524725e61788d8078c900afa"
},"Shifts": [
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "524725e61788d8078c900afb"
        },
        "StartTime": {
            "$date": "2013-10-20T15:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "EndTime": {
            "$date": "2013-10-20T17:00:00.000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "524725e61788d8078c900b22"
        },
        "StartTime": {
            "$date": "2013-10-21T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "EndTime": {
            "$date": "2013-10-21T02:00:00.000Z"
        }
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/).  When you match an array element in the query part of the update, using `$` will update the "matched" element.  See the docs for more details.